# Boost::pool::free() performance

Tags: c++, memory-management

Does anyone know the correct Big O performance for Boost::pool::free()? I'm writing some performance C++ critical code and it makes a big difference? The below is from the Boost documentation but it's kind of confusing. Is it O(1) or O(n)?

void free(void *const chunk);
Same as malloc, only allocates enough contiguous chunks to cover n * requested_size bytes. Amortized O(n).

Deallocates a chunk of memory. Note that chunk may not be 0. O(1).

Chunk must have been previously returned by t.malloc() or t.ordered_malloc(). Assumes that chunk actually refers to a block of chunks spanning n * partition_sz bytes. deallocates each chunk in that block. Note that chunk may not be 0. O(n).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Boost Pool free efficiency O(n) or O(1)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288375/is-boost-pool-free-efficiency-on-or-o1)